# If $q$ is a prime, $gcd(x(x+2),q\#)=1$ and $q < x < q^2$, doesn't it follow that $x,x+2$ are twin primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I recently asked a question that was not well received.  That's ok.  I don't disagree with the ratings if my question is unclear.  I want to verify the foundation of my reasoning.

Doesn't it follow if:

- $q$ is prime
- $q\#$ is the primorial for $q$
- $\gcd(x(x+2),q\#)=1$
- $q<x<q^2$

Then:

$x,x+2$ are twin primes.

Please let me know if I am making a mistake.

Comment: I believe this is true, but can you show your proof or reasoning why this should be true?

Comment: This is true; are you asking for a proof?

Comment: I would think this is true for the following reason.  Assume $x$ is not a prime so that there exists a prime $p < x$ that divides $x$.  We can assume that $p \le \sqrt{x}$ since if $p > \sqrt{x}$, then there exists another prime $t$ such that $t = \frac{x}{p}$ and necessarily $t < \sqrt{x}$.  Since $p \le \sqrt{x}$, it follows that $p^2 \le x < q^2$ and further that $p < q$ which is a contradiction since $\gcd(x(x+2),q\#)=1$.